# React and AWS Amplify - Displaying different page based on groups a Cognito user is a member of

Tags: reactjs, authentication, promise, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create a React app that has multiple different types of users (tutors, students and admins). I want to create a separate home page for each (e.g. mydomain/tutors, mydomain/students etc). I want only the correct members to be able to view the actual content for those pages.

I'm using AWS Amplify for the app and user authentication. Users are part of User Pool Groups already. I can get the user details from the AWS database, however this returns a Promise object which seems to break the React rendering.
I think I need to stop the page trying to render until the Promise object has been fulfilled.

I've tried using states but I wasn't able to get that to work (I may have implemented them incorrectly).

I'm open to any solutions.

My current app that attempts to check if the user is a tutor in order to display the correct page

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import React from 'react';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

//Function to return the currently signed in user
async function getUser() {
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    return user;
}

//Function to determine whether the user is a tutor or not
async function isTutor(user) {
    console.log("User given to isTutor function: " + user);
    //Get a list of groups the user is a member of
    const groups = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"];
    //Return true if the user is a member of the 'Tutors' Group
    const isATutor = groups.includes('Tutors');
    console.log("User is a tutor: " + isATutor);
    return isATutor;
}

//Function that returns the correct page based on whether the user is a tutor or not
function TutorHome() {
    if (isTutor() == true) {
        console.log("Is a tutor")
        return (
            <TutorHomeValid />
        );
      }
    else {
        console.log("Isn't a tutor")
        return (
            <TutorHomeNotValid />
        );
    }
}

//Export back up to index.js where it is rendered
//Enforce user login using 'withAuthenticator'
export default withAuthenticator(TutorHome);
```

The problem is the getUser function returns a Promise that is unfulfilled when it attempts to check if the user is a tutor.

Console logs:

```
User given to isTutor function: [object Promise]
TutorHome.jsx:80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accessToken')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and componentDidMount() to solve that this way you can check the group when you are rendering the object

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import React from 'react';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
class TutorHome extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      group:''
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
  const user =  await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
  const groupname = user.signInUserSession.accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"][0]
  this.setState({ group:groupname });

  }
  render(){
    const { group }= this.state
  if (group === "Tutors")
     return (
         <TutorHomeValid />
     )
  else
     return (
         <TutorHomeNotValid />
     )
  export default withAuthenticator(TutorHome);
```